# How to change naming of core dumps in unix-like operating systems?

Tags: linux, unix, multi-core, dump

I want to change naming of core dumps for a separate process and its childs or, if it is impossible, for all processes of a separate user.

NOTE: I know that it is possible to change the naming for all users overwriting `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` file.

Answer (score 4):

As you know, `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` is system-global, and Linux-specific (not portable).

I don't think there's a facility to customize core dump filenames on a per-process or per-uid basis, but you might be able to to achieve what you want by sending core dumps to a handler program instead of directly to a file. By doing something like this:

```
echo "|usr/local/bin/my_core_dump_handler" >/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

`my_core_dump_handler` will be executed each time a core dump occurs. It can read the actual core dump on its standard input and write it to a customized filename of its choosing.

**BTW**: Your question talks about `/proc/sys/kernel/core_name_format`. I am assuming you mean `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` because the former doesn't exist for me.